# What similar words can I use for 'chemistry' in the context of sports?

Tags: word-request

Consider this expression:

> **Chemistry** between player X and player Y helped their team to win the championship three times in a row.
>
> Even though team X has got tons of great players, still they never win anything as there is no **chemistry** between their star players, they all play **individually**.

Can anyone suggest similar words to 'chemistry' in this context?

Comment: In the second sentence, I think the last two clauses are not connected correctly. Maybe it could be written "...between their star players, as they all play individually."

Comment: This is a tough one. Chemistry is not used to imply attraction. We are talking about two players whose playing styles are compatible to each other or can coordinate well on the field.

Comment: @EnglishLearner: Actually, _chemistry_ **is** used in that context; [here are some examples](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&safe=active&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22good+chemistry+on+the+team%22&oq=%22good+chemistry+on+the+team%22&gs_l=hp.3...2199.8347.0.8642.32.24.2.0.0.0.439.4809.1j16j2j4j1.24.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.6.psy-ab.x0WxMOvBP54&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43828540,d.dmg&fp=48b21a1831f5683c&biw=1536&bih=850). Also, see [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/chemistry) definition #2 and [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/chemistry) def #4.

Comment: I think _chemistry_ is such a fitting word here that I'm wondering why you are looking for a replacement. But if you really must use a different word or phrase, you could say that players X and Y _clicked_.

Comment: @user3169 It could also be written "...between their star players; they all play individually", which seems more like what was intended, but the writer may not have known how to use a semicolon.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first one being just a pair of players there are terms like *alignment*, *rhythm*, *harmony*, *synchronicity*, and *magic* that would seem appropriate.

*Teamwork*, *collaboration*, *unity*, and *cohesion* would be more appropriate for the second since this is talking about a larger set of players.

If you want a term for both, *collaboration* would be my suggestion.

As for Matt's suggestions:

*Spark* could work as, "The spark between Jordan and Pippen helped their team to win the championships for the Chicago Bulls."

*X-Factor* can be a bit more tricky as each person has part of the recipe here and not all of it since the idea is that these players coming together brought great success.

*Rapport* would likely require one to have the understanding that this is within the context of playing the game together rather than just having an understanding within communications.

In the second context, another phrase one could use is that, *"The whole is more than the sum of the parts,"* as the idea is that a team with *chemistry* can do more than what each player could do alone.

Comment: +1. Also, how about "spark", "x-factor" and "rapport"?

Answer (score 3):

I would replace chemistry with either coordination or Unity.

> Coordination/Unity between player X and player Y helped win the championship 3 times in a row.
>
> Even though team X has got tons of great players, still they never win anything as there is no coordination/unity between their star players, they all play individually.

Comment: _Unity_ isn't a bad word, particularly when getting through tough times together, but _coordination_ isn't very apt at all here.

Comment: @JR, I’m looking at online thesaurus (http://thesaurus.com/browse/chemistry?s=t). Coordination is listed under similar word for chemistry (when used as organization). I’m wondering if the original sentence is referring ‘chemistry’ as to the playing style (in field) between the players or something more (personal relationship, behavior, aptitude, compatibility). And I agree that the word coordination seems to be very limited to just playing style.

Comment: In the realm of sport, _coordination_ often brings to mind athletic ability (an antonym of _clumsy_); see the second definition [here](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/coordination). While _coordination_ can indeed be used to describe harmonious interaction, that word would be a poor choice in this context, I think.

Answer (score 3):

in the UK it is not uncommon to hear the phrases

> player X and player Y have a **good understanding**.

or

> player X and player Y have a **good partnership**.

These are especially common in the context of football (soccer) but it wouldn't be out of place to use them in non sporting contexts either.